# setting a div to have the same height as another div with jQuery CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am having an issue attempting to set the height of a div with jQuery based on the height of the div sitting next to it. Basically, I have two divs and I want them both to be the same height. The left div will change in height and has no height element set in the CSS/HTML. The right div can also change height, but the left one will always be bigger.

This is my attempt below at setting the right one (`#p_window`) to the same as `.c_content_right`. *(Ignore the strange naming conventions)*

```
if ($('.c_content_right').length) {        
        if ($('.c_content_right').height() > $('#p_window').height()) {
            $('#p_window').css('height', $('.c_content_right').height() + 'px');    
        }                    
}
```

Here is a 
[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MfrqA/)

Comment: P.S: you're missing the jQuery library in your jsFiddle demo, but anyway:

Comment: Seems like the height values are the same... need more checking... EDIT: someone beat me to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MfrqA/1/)*

If you have paddings, to calculate the total height use: `outerHeight()`:

```
  var catH = $('.category_content_right').outerHeight();

  if ( catH  > $('#product_window').height() ){
      $('#product_window').height( catH  );    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working fiddle based on yours.

http://jsfiddle.net/MfrqA/10/

- Your fiddle wasn't set to jQuery.
- I get confused in jQuery while adding CSS, if I don't just set the variables outside it, because there are several syntaxes you can use, and I always get caught up.
- If your edits don't work, then add an alert inside the 'if' loop, to see if you got that far.